Scipy.optimize.least_square sensitive to order of inputs
The following code generate different results depending on the order of the inputs I pass on. Why is that? I'd expect least square optimization to reach same result no matter what order the inputs are passed to the error generating function. What is it exactly that create this discrepancy?
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

def dummy_func(Y, T):
    # Define fn to optimize
    def func(X):
        tau = X[0]
        C1 = X[1]
        C2 = X[2]
        C3 = X[3]
        C4 = X[4]
        L0 = X[5]
        S1 = X[6]
        exp_tt1 = np.exp(- T / tau)
        f1 = (1 - exp_tt1) / (T / tau)
        f2 = 2 * f1 - exp_tt1 * (T / tau)
        f3 = 3 * f2 - exp_tt1 * (T / tau) ** 2
        f4 = 4 * f3 - exp_tt1 * (T / tau) ** 3
        f5 = 5 * f4 - exp_tt1 * (T / tau) ** 4
        y_hat = L0 + S1 * f1 + C1 * f2 + C2 * f3 + C3 * f4 + C4 * f5
        errs = Y - y_hat
        return errs
    return func

# starting point and boundaries
initial_params = np.array([ 10,   0,   0,   0,   0, 100,   0])
bounds_lower = np.array([ 3,   -500,   -1e3,   -100,   -15, 0,   -1e3])
bounds_upper = np.array([ 15,   500,   1e3,   100,   15, 1e5,   1e3])

# inputs
Y = np.array([5, 6, 7])
T = np.array([1, 1.5, 1.6])

# Get min function
min_fn = dummy_func(Y, T)

# Fit
res = least_squares(min_fn,
                    initial_params,
                    bounds=(bounds_lower, bounds_upper),
                    ftol=1e-3,
                    loss="linear", 
                    verbose=0)

# swap items 1 and 2
T_swap = T.copy()
Y_swap = Y.copy()
ix1 = 1
ix2 = 2
T_swap[[ix1, ix2]] = T[[ix2, ix1]]
Y_swap[[ix1, ix2]] = Y[[ix2, ix1]]

# Get min function
min_fn_swap = dummy_func(Y_swap, T_swap)

# Fit
res_swap = least_squares(min_fn_swap,
                         initial_params,
                         bounds=(bounds_lower, bounds_upper),
                         ftol=1e-3,
                         loss="linear", 
                         verbose=0)

print(f"same results? {all(res.x == res_swap.x)} \n res.x: {res.x} \nres_swap.x: {res_swap.x}")

This produces the following output:
same results? False 
 res.x: [   3.00001277  310.88942015  300.69037515  -40.34027084   -9.85586819
   43.96214131 -290.54867755] 
res_swap.x: [  10.28332721   86.26342455  -67.14921168    8.76243152    0.51657765
   93.50701816 -133.10992102]


@Reinderien Y and T should not be interchangeable and I do not expect them to be. If you look at the code what I am swapping is not Y and T but specific positions of values, items 2 in both Y and T becomes items 1, and vice versa. And I am surprised this yield different results

Please show the objective value for both scenarios.

When I run it, the cost outputs are very close to each other - well within your ftol. So it's not surprising that the optimiser may consider the two scenarios equivalent, even if the objectives are not exactly the same.

Could you define what is meant by "objectives" and "scenarios" here? Want to make sure I understand you correctly

Scenarios are first (noninverted) and second (inverted). Objective is synonymous with the cost member of the result object.

What does that mean in layman terms? Here I would expect to land on the same solution regardless of the order of inputs passed on. The error vector is the same, just in a different order, so why does it land on a different solution when it tries to minimize the errors?

Let's please continue in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257654/scipy-optimize-least-square-sensitive-to-order-of-inputs

This problem has many minima. So the order of the data makes the parameter X to converge to different points just by the inner working of the minimization algorithm. To have many minima is expected since the number of X parameters (7) is larger than the number of data (3). I suggest you to reduce the tolerance to the default value (1e-08) and to print the result to gain more insight:
 print(res)
 message: `xtol` termination condition is satisfied.
 success: True
  status: 3
     fun: [-1.364e-12 -1.478e-12  3.297e-12]
       x: [ 3.011e+00  3.578e+02  1.724e+02 -2.350e+01 -6.728e+00
            1.273e+02 -4.763e+02]
    cost: 7.45755021004839e-24
    ...

 print(res_swap)
 message: `xtol` termination condition is satisfied.
 success: True
  status: 3
     fun: [ 6.935e-03  3.849e-02 -4.544e-02]
       x: [ 3.000e+00  2.502e+02  1.367e+02 -7.926e+00 -5.857e+00
            2.139e+02 -6.154e+02]
    cost: 0.001797285633783842

The cost of the original data is close to 0 bar numerical rounding. As zero is the lowest possible value of the cost, this is a global minimum. However, the cost of the swapped data is larger than the cost of the original data. The minimization converged to a local minimum in the second case.
Try different initial parameters and you will even reach other minima. For example, I tried:
initial_params = np.array([ 10,   0,   0,   0,   0, 1,   0])
and obtained
 print(res)
 message: `xtol` termination condition is satisfied.
 success: True
  status: 3
     fun: [ 1.846e-03 -1.206e-02  1.021e-02]
       x: [ 3.000e+00  2.808e+02  2.788e+02 -2.415e+01 -1.153e+01
            5.636e+01 -3.003e+02]
    cost: 0.00012653248779190626

So, by changing some of the conditions the minimization will converge to very different X's. To have a single minimum more data than parameters are needed.

Thanks. What exactly make the cost different when inputs are re ordered?

I guess I am still not understanding what exactly in inner workings of the optimizer set it on a different (yet still deterministic) path when inputs are re-ordered

I understand concept of local minima but don’t get why we would get to a different one if inputs are re ordered. As problem is essentially the same, albeit formulated with a slight difference in order

Both data converge to the same point if the boundary conditions are removed. The second solution is hitting the boundary 3 for X[0]

How did you figure this out? And do you understand the why as well? What makes the second scenario hit the boundary while the first one doesn't?

When minimizing a function within boudaries there is always a possibility that the minimum is at the limit. An straight line within an interval for example. This is the reason why the second scenario hits the limit, the gradient of the minimized function points toward the boundary

Thanks a ton @Diego. What makes the gradient different between the two scenarios? Intuitively it feels like it should be the same
